# I am facing error when I create dataset in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

Error:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

case class Drug(S_No: int,Name: string,Drug_Name: string,Gender: string,Drug_Value: int)

scala> val ds=spark.read.csv("file:///home/xxx/drug_detail.csv").as[Drug]
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`S_No`' given input columns: [_c1, _c2, _c3, _c4, _c0];
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:110)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:107)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:277)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:275)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:275)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:275)
```

Here is my test data:

```
1,Brandon Buckner,avil,female,525
2,Veda Hopkins,avil,male,633
3,Zia Underwood,paracetamol,male,980
4,Austin Mayer,paracetamol,female,338
5,Mara Higgins,avil,female,153
6,Sybill Crosby,avil,male,193
7,Tyler Rosales,paracetamol,male,778
8,Ivan Hale,avil,female,454
9,Alika Gilmore,paracetamol,female,833
10,Len Burgess,metacin,male,325
```

Comment: For your future questions, please try to put the description in the body, even if you think the title is self-explanatory. Add test data into the question too, in a formatted block, rather than in comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate `structtype` schema by using `sql encoders` then pass the `schema` while reading the csv file and define types in case class as `Int,String` instead of lower case `int,string`.

**`Example:`**

**`Sample data:`**

```
cat drug_detail.csv
1,foo,bar,M,2
2,foo1,bar1,F,3
```

---

**`Spark-shell:`**

```
case class Drug(S_No: Int,Name: String,Drug_Name: String,Gender: String,Drug_Value: Int)

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val schema = Encoders.product[Drug].schema

val ds=spark.read.schema(schema).csv("file:///home/xxx/drug_detail.csv").as[Drug]

 ds.show()
//+----+----+---------+------+----------+
//|S_No|Name|Drug_Name|Gender|Drug_Value|
//+----+----+---------+------+----------+
//|   1| foo|      bar|     M|         2|
//|   2|foo1|     bar1|     F|         3|
//+----+----+---------+------+----------+
```

Comment: its working..Thanks shu.could you please tell me the reason to add schema variable(2nd line).

Comment: @KarthikaDavid, As column names are not matching we need to add schema to create a dataset, if your csv file have header in it and you can do this way **`spark.read.option("header",true).option("inferSchema",true).csv("<file_path>").as[Drug].show()`** this will work if your inferSchema matches the types defined in `case class` only..

Answer (score 0):

use as :

```
val ds=spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("file:///home/xxx/drug_detail.csv").as[Drug]
```

Comment: @KarthikaDavid can you provide top 10 records from file drug_detail.csv

Answer (score 0):

If your csv file contains headers, maybe include option("header","true").

e.g.: `spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("...").as[Drug]`

Comment: should i specify the column names in the first line of the file.

Comment: Yep. Like: `S_No,Name,Drug_Name,Gender,Drug_Value`